# :GetChildren() not working for an unknown reason

Tags: lua, roblox

so, i'm trying to make a baldi's basics type game

(here's my code for the hearing script)

```
local baldi = script.Parent
local neededConfig = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.modules.configs.tags)
local targ = baldi.Target
local crime = targ.Crime
local minDistance = 200

function getHRP(c:Model)
    local t = c:GetChildren()

    for _, part in pairs(t) do
        if part:IsA("BasePart") then
            if part.Name == "HumanoidRootPart" then
                return part
            end
        end
    end

    return nil
end

function speedup(boostTime, briefSpeedup)
    baldi.Speed.Value += briefSpeedup

    task.delay(boostTime, function()
        baldi.Speed.Value -= briefSpeedup
    end)
end

function listen()
    local nearest = minDistance

    crime.Value = "baldi"

    for _, p in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        local c = game.Players:FindFirstChild(p.Name, true).Character

        if getHRP(c) ~= nil then
            local hrp = getHRP(c)
            local dist = (hrp.Position - baldi.HumanoidRootPart.Position).magnitude

            if dist <= nearest and c:HasTag(neededConfig.tags.sound) then
                nearest = dist
                targ.Value = p

                if baldi.Wandering.Value ~= 0 then
                    speedup(15, 1.25)
                    baldi.Wandering.Value = 0

                    task.delay(30, function()
                        baldi.Wandering.Value = 1
                    end)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

spawn(function()
    repeat
        task.wait()
        listen()
    until baldi == nil
end)
```

on line 8 when i call GetChildren, it errors saying `attempted to index nil with GetChildren` and i cant figure out why

i havent seen any solutions yet, so i'm just kind of confused as to why my code is failing

Comment: Well, the thing you pass to `getHRP()` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AKX pointed out, the error is telling you that for some reason `c` is nil. So you need to look where you call `getHRP`...

```lua
    for _, p in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        local c = game.Players:FindFirstChild(p.Name, true).Character

        if getHRP(c) ~= nil then
```

When a player joins the game or has just died, there is a brief time where their Character model doesn't exist. So `player.Character` will be `nil` until their character respawns in the world.

So you need to add safety checks so you aren't trying to access an object that doesn't exist :

```lua
    for _, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        local c = player.Character
        if c and getHRP(c) ~= nil then
```